# Why a fuse blow in my house?

Tags: appliances

Yesterday, I had an issue with our electricity in our house. All power points in a kitchen, bathroom, and a small room suddenly stopped working, but not other rooms. I opened a fuse box to check if there were any broken wires, and I found one fuse was disconnected. It seems that it was burnt as I could see black burnt marks nearby.

My question is that what might have caused this fuse blow? I have a housemate who uses a small electrical heater which uses 2000w in his room, and he leaves it switched on during the night. Does it have something to do with his heater or it sometimes happens as time goes by?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2000W is **not** a small heater. By itself it draws pretty much all the available power from the circuit it's on, so if there's anything else on the same circuit you're going to have problems. Like blown fuses...

Comment: It looks very small though. So, he should not use the heater or use less powerful heater?

Comment: Please specify which country this is, as those of us on 240V systems can have heaters up to 3kw without problems ...

Comment: I live in Australia

Comment: Add up the load currents on the circuit and compare with the fuse rating. If "all power points in the kitchen" (presumably excluding the cooker which should have its own circuit) included a kettle (up to 2.7kw) toaster etc as well as that 2kw heater you may exceed the fuse rating.